# Классы камеры ios для изменения частоты кадров и разрешения

Tags: ios, библиотеки, камера

Написал камеру на айфоне. Выяснилось, что основной класс который там используется `UIImagePickerController`  - отдаёт ссылку на нативный рекордер. То есть съемка фото\видео осуществляется с помощью нативного приложения, которое открывается поверх моего.
Мне нужно написать такую камеру, чтобы можно было получить и изменить:

- Оригинальную частоту кадров
- Разрешение

Какие классы, методы, библиотеки и фрэймворки нужно использовать для решения этой задачи?

Comment: у вашего `UIImagePickerController` есть свойство `videoQuality` оно задает разрешение. Насчет частоты кадров вряд ли вы сможете ее менять при записи, я бы предложил посмотреть классы редактирования уже записанного видео.

Comment: Частоту кадров точно как-то можно менять. Я уже встречал ios приложения, в которых варьируется частота.

Comment: я уверен, что все это можно сделать при помощи AVFoundation. но очень сомневаюсь, что UIImagePickerController чем то вам поможет в плане изменения частоты кадров

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `UIImagePickerController` является самым простым и не функциональным  способом обратиться к камере. Фрэймворк, который позволяет изменять характеристики получаемого видео - `AVFoundation`. Так же нужно использовать  фрэймворк `CoreMedia`.

В частности, за частоту кадров отвечает метод  `CMTimeShow`. Примерно таким, способом можно получить частоту кадров:

```
CMTimeShow(CaptureConnection.videoMinFrameDuration); //минимальная скорость кадров в секунду.
```

Или так

```
CMTimeShow(CaptureConnection.videoMaxFrameDuration); //максимальная скорость кадров в секунду.
```

В вариантах реализации метода можно задать более детально частоту кадра.

**З**а разрешение отвечает метод `sessionPreset`. Так можно реализовать изменение настроек разрешения:

```
[CaptureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetLow]; //установить низкое разрешение.
```

Или так

```
[CaptureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh]; //установить высокое разрешение
```

Хороший работающий код, с комментариями на английском языке по вопросу изменения разрешения и частоты кадров приведен [здесь.](http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/camera/record-video-with-avcapturesession-2)